# Firefox 33 does not display specified fonts

Tags: firefox, barcode

The problem is with firefox 33. The previous version 29 didn't show this problem. I need to show a barcode in a page. I have the necessary font which correctly displays the barcode when installed. Presently IE(in Windows) and Firefox 29(both in Windows and Ubuntu) display it properly. No sooner had I upgraded to Firefox 33 it shows only the numbers even inspite of checking the "Allow pages to choose their own fonts." in Fonts options.

Please help.

PS: Please find the html file as well as the font [here](http://forums.techguy.org/attachments/235738d1414666892/firefox-files.rar)

Comment: So it works in ff 29 both Windows and Ubuntu. You mentioned the fonts doesn't work in ff 33 Ubuntu. What about ff 33 Windows, does it work?

Comment: No. Neither does it work in Windows! I know in that case it reduces simply to Firefox problem, but I am waiting for someone here to answer if they figure it out.

Comment: Please try with the Font and HTML file. If you have FF33 you may readily realise.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here! You can use a quick but dirty fix... just prevent firefox using "other" fonts.

Preferences, Content, Advanced, and finally uncheck Allow pages bla bla bla...
(sorry, I don't speak english and have firefox spanish version, but I uploaded an screenshot)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: We should 'allow' the pages to choose the font.Tried unchecking though. But checking or unchecking the option affects nothing here and that's the problem.We should actually 'check' it and it should work as in FF29/30 or IE .